# How to conditionally stop loading a React app's scripts on unsupported browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So my project is using create-react-app, the `<script/>` with the React `main.js` is loaded at the bottom of `<body/>`. When it loads, it crashes on unsupported browsers.

I have a block in a `<script/>` above the `main.js` one, it checks your browser and conditionally doesn't render `<div id='roor'/>`, but a call to action to go update your browser. When that call to action is displayed, I had a `window.stop()` at the end, so the browser doesn't load the react script. Unfortunately, the images also fail to low.

Is there a way to stop loading the React js? Or maybe a way to preload the images in the ?

Example structure:

```
<body>
  <script>
     Script 1 here, checking browser version and using `document.write()` if 
     unsupported
  </script>
  <script>
    React script here, which shouldn't run/be imported if the above script 
    found an unsupported browser.
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your approach is already good. You could actually render a div element and overlay it on top of everything, so your users won't see the rest of the broken page. **However**, if you want to have a non-broken page, you need to eject your project and tinker with your webpack config, so it won't append `main.js` to your project. You could then just append it yourself and only load the script when the browser is supported.

Comment: Instead of checking for browser incompatibility you should check for browser compatibility in your first script and only load the 2nd react script if the browser is compatible, which you can do by dynamically adding a script tag to the page using JS.

Comment: The React script is added at build time, as `lumio` mentioned I'd need to eject the application to change it, which for this project isn't an option.

Comment: Hit enter prematurely and then took more than 5 minutes to edit the comment, so I couldn't actually edit it.

There are a few undefined values due to div#root missing so whatever the first script tries to render doesn't even show up. I'll try add fallbacks and see if script 2 just fails silently. 

If that fails, another option might be to redirect to a separate page that doesn't have the React script at all, then I can let it load everything in peace. I'll post results later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was a lot simpler, instead of generating the alternative 'Browser not supported' html in `index.html`, I set up a redirect to another html file when an unsupported browser was found. This way I didn't have to generate the tags with `document.write`, which spared me the annoyance of a multi-line string. Everything loads properly, there's no react script imported, nothing needs to be ejected, the page is much more customizable, css is easier to apply and `back` is disabled by `window.location.replace()`. Feels good.

Comment: What does the script look like, and did you use webpack to deploy it?

Comment: @adam-gerthel The project was bootstrapped with create-react-app, the script was in `/public/index.html`, which at build time is changed and added to the `/build` folder. 

Script's too lengthy for a comment so here's a pastebin, expires in about a week, not sure if there's a better way to include it here:

[pastebin script link](https://pastebin.com/pg5bV7Yg)